# Cordova geolocation and navigator not working

Tags: cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition worked well in the Visual Studio Cordova project but it does not work anymore. Later, there was also an error that navigator.connection.type is always "none".

These appeared after the last Visual Studio Community update.
The old version works well on the devices.

Has anyone else had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with a bug in the latest Chrome (65). Still trying to find a workaround myself https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820945#c8